# Crosswords Generator application

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation, games

I am looking for a crosswords generator similar to **Eclipse Crossword** (http://www.eclipsecrossword.com/), which can be used in **Ubuntu 14.04**. Can someone please refer me such an application?

Comment: I bet that program can be used with PlayOnLinux/Wine.

Comment: I am searching for a native Ubuntu app instead of using Windows software with Wine

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1587246

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick `apt-cache search crossword | grep crossword` returned the following results:

```
qxw - advanced interactive crossword construction tool
xword - Reads and writes crossword puzzles in the Across Lite file format
```

To install both:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qxw xword
```

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest QXW! The link for the homepage (of QWX) is [here.](http://www.quinapalus.com/qxwdownload.html) To install, type `sudo apt-get install qxw`